# Error "mysqld dead but pid file exists"

Tags: mysql-error-1064

I get the error "mysqld dead but pid file exists"

I have a acache webclient running on EC2. With WordPress. I started seeing "error in Databse Connection"

When i do a sudo service mysqld status i See the error "mysqld dead but pid file exists"

Looks like I have enough space

```
   [root@ip-10-0-0-149 log]# df -h
   Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
   /dev/xvda1      7.8G  1.5G  6.3G  19% /
   devtmpfs        486M   56K  486M   1% /dev
   tmpfs           499M     0  499M   0% /dev/shm
```

Also when i do a tail I get

```
   InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
   InnoDB: buffer...
   140717 21:04:58  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
   140717 21:04:59 InnoDB: 5.5.38 started; log sequence number 6150055
   140717 21:04:59 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
   140717 21:04:59 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
   140717 21:04:59 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
   140717 21:04:59 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
   140717 21:04:59 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
   Version: '5.5.38'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Please Help !

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I have the same issue.

Comment: @bart59 : I too have the same issue. Any fix?

Comment: I too am having a similar problem with the solution still unclear.

Answer (score 6):

in my case I did this and my problem solved.

```
  cd /var/run/mysqld
  rm -f mysqld.pid
```

Comment: in 2019 it throw this error `ERROR! MySQL PID file could not be found!` when I try to start it after deleting pid file.